# Interaction control variables in a difference-in-difference regression

Tags: panel-data, difference-in-difference, controlling-for-a-variable

I have a question with regards to control variables in a difference-in-difference regression. I would like to know the difference between including single control variables and including control variables that interact with the treatment variable.

For instance, in this paper by [(Dottling, 2020)](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3656756) the authors use single control variables such as *log(TNA)* in Table 2 but also control variables that interact with the treatment variable such as *Healthcare Sector X COVID* in Table 12. **My question:** what is the difference between these single controls and the controls that interact with the treatment effect?

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I believe they interact some of their controls with the “post-treatment” indicator. Are you sure you’re referring to Table 2?

Comment: @ThomasBilach thank you for your reply. My apologies, I meant the "post-treatment" indicator indeed. Yes, I'm referring to Table 2 and Table 12, in which the authors use "single" and "interaction" controls.